# Apache really slow with alias

Tags: apache

I face a really strange issue with Apache2 (v2.4.7).
Our sites have both domain.com and www.domain.com, with and without HTTPS

When I only enable one of them with SSL, it response take less than 0.01s.
When I enable both of them with SSL, it takes more than 1 minute to answer.

There's no issue with "classic" HTTP configuration file, only the one with SSL

I've tried both with independent configuration files, or with aliases. No matter, more or less the same big response time.

Here's the config file:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName domain.com
        ServerAlias www.domain.com # Fast when commented, slow when enabled
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/site
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/site-error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/site-access.log combined
        <Directory "/var/www/site/blog">
            AllowOverride All
            Options FollowSymLinks
            allow from all
            order allow,deny
        </Directory>
        SSLEngine On
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com-0001/cert.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com-0001/privkey.pem
        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com-0001/chain.pem
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Do you have any idea how to fix this or where does the issue comes from?

Thank you for help ;)

Comment: Sorry for the missing "hello", edition seems not to work

Comment: Please read: [What kind of behavior is expected of users?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) - **Do not use signature, taglines, or greetings**. Also, [please do not add thanks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262087/2675154).

Answer (score 0):

That's strange. Are you sure if you have mod_alias enabled and loaded? You can find that out by issuing this command on a ssh console:

```
httpd -t -D DUMP_MODULES | grep alias
```

What you can try though it this: Get your server's ip (no matter if it's private or public) from your main ethernet card and use it in your apache configuration.

Replace:
`<VirtualHost *:443>` with `<VirtualHost server-ip:443>` for all your vhosts

Restart apache and try again

Comment: Yes, mod_alias is enable and works well (other similar websites added as aliases works (.eu, .fr, .co.uk)